# Mock microservices in integration tests in python

Tags: python, testing, mocking, microservices, integration

right now i am working with python microservices that communicates with http calls or kafka. I have really a bunch of integration tests: right now everyone of them calls other microservices to run. This means a lot of inconsistency, variability etc. etc.
I would like to mock the response of those services and the kafka messages to test in a isolate environment, independent from the other microservices.

I saw that python-pact could be a good choice but it seems like that there is no way to auto generate the contracts from the existing integration tests: all the packages that used to do this are now deprecated.
Help me, please!